# How to retrieve data By id firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How to retrieve data By id firebase 
  i am trying with this

```
        //get zone details 
        db.collection('zone').where('id','==','8JQb8o3RJWm5bTwR8qOZ').get().then(snap =>{
        // get childs data 


         snap.docs.forEach(doc =>{

          this.setState({zone:doc._data});


        })
      })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Peter's excellent answer on how to get the data from a snapshot, if `8JQb8o3RJWm5bTwR8qOZ` is the ID of the document, you'll want to load it with this:

```
db.collection('zone').doc('8JQb8o3RJWm5bTwR8qOZ').get().then(doc =>{
  this.setState({ zone:doc.data() });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`snap` is of type [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html), if you want to iterate inside the document, you can then use `forEach` on the variable `snap`:

```
snap.forEach(doc =>{
 console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
```

and retrieve the data by using the method [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.html#data).